# ElasticSearch script to update if the value not exist

Tags: java, elasticsearch, upsert, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to update an es document using `Java`.
My document is as follows

```
"_source": {

    "gender": "male" ,
    "names": ["name1"]

}
```

I need to add more names to `names` list. But I want no duplicates.
How can I update an array in an ES document without duplicate values?

I tried something like this. But it's not working.

```
client.prepareUpdate(index,type,id)
         .addScriptParam("newobject", "newName")
        .setScript("ctx._source.names.contains(newobject) ? ctx.op = \"none\" :  ctx._source.names+=newobject ").execute().actionGet();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea would be to simply call [`unique()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#unique()) on the resulting list:

```
client.prepareUpdate(index,type,id)
         .addScriptParam("newobject", "newName")
        .setScript("ctx._source.names+=newobject; ctx._source.names = ctx._source.names.unique(); ").execute().actionGet();
```

Also for this to work, you need to make sure that [scripting is enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting).